# iterative integration problem

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, integration-by-parts

I'm working on a numerical analysis problem that requires me to find an iterative solution to (1). The resulting integral should take the form (2). However, I cannot figure out what method to use. I first attempted integration by parts, but the most obvious choice of $u = x^n$ and $dv = dx/(x+5)$ results in (3), which isn't what I need. What am I missing?

[Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTele.png))

Comment: It's just polynomial long division (and then computing $\int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx = 1/n$).

Comment: Thank you, it's been over 5 years since I've done this sort of problem.